# Using "reverse" text only when wanted with Perl Curses::UI::Label

Tags: perl, text, label, reverse, curses

I'm developing a Perl Curses::UI interface and I've come across a little problem I can't find a solution to.

One of the Label widget-specific options is "reverse":

```
-reverse < BOOLEAN >
If BOOLEAN is true, text on the label will be drawn in a reverse font.
```

Basically, the text appears written white on black foreground, like nano and many more CLI interfaces use to do for pointing out CTRL combinations.

The point is, if you set a Label to be "reversed" the whole text gets white-on-black. I'd like to alternate normal text to white-on-black instead of having the whole text like that.
I've tried looking at UI.pm and UI/Common.pm but - my bad - I can't figure out how it actually does that so that I could do it on my own in the text field of the Label. I've also tried using Term::ANSIColor but it just prints out the related escape sequences. It basically treats everything contained in the text field as pure string, being it quoted or not.

Any suggestions how I could proceed? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't appear to be supported by the underlying Curses interface, or at least not by the Perl XS one.

Depending on how complex your needs are, it might be easiest to just break the label up into multiple separate labels, each with their own `-reverse` setting. Note that you'll have to specify the width of all but the last label (to prevent overlap), and the x-coordinate of all but the first label (to shift to the end of the word).

For example:

```
$win->add( undef, 'Label', -x => 0, -width => 3, -text => 'Hel', -reverse => 1 );
$win->add( undef, 'Label', -x => 3, -width => 3, -text => 'lo!' );
```

Check out [this PerlMonks post](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=852274) for a creative solution to the same problem.